# Is there difference between Quaternion.Euler(Obj.transform.rotation.x,Obj.transform.rotation.y,Obj.transform.rotation.z) and Obj.transform.rotation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I was trying to design a weapon that fires bullets a few degrees less or more than the angle it makes when following the mouse. I was using this code to launch a projectile:

```
GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, FirePoint.transform.position,Gun.transform.rotation);
bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(bullet.transform.up * -2000);
```

It was working well. Then i changed it into this when i was trying to change trajectory of the bullet.

```
GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, FirePoint.transform.position,Quaternion.Euler(Gun.transform.rotation.x, Gun.transform.rotation.y, Gun.transform.rotation.z));
bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(bullet.transform.up * -2000);
```

and it started to fire it only downwards even if i move the mouse to different position and i didnt understand why.

Is there any difference between `Gun.transform.rotation` and `Quaternion.Euler(Gun.transform.rotation.x, Gun.transform.rotation.y, Gun.transform.rotation.z)`?  And is there any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you get rotation.x you get the x component of Quaternion (x,y,z,w) and in your case you need Euler Angles so get rotation.eulerAngles.x